# Visualization in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

[image: The left part is the data, and the right part is my desire output in the Power BI]

I am new to Power BI Desktop and Power BI Query. The left part is the data, and the right part is my desired output in Power BI. I tried to use the Matrix Report Visual to format my data like the table on the right, but it only allowed me to select the Product column in the row. I hope to get the desired output without creating separate tables for each quarter.

Comment: I put all necessary column names in the row(the first three) section, then used the 4th icon on the top right to expand all levels in the hierarchy, and hide the +/- icon.

Comment: In future please post data as text not images. We dont want to retype things to help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could bring your data into powerquery, and use this code to transform the data.  You'd have to modify it to show your actual table name (Table1) and the name of the columns as appropriate.  It basically groups on index/product to find the most recent target sale, expands the data back, then pivots to get the sideways view

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"index", "product"}, {
    {"data", each   _, type table },
    {"most_recent_target_sale", each  Table.Sort(_,{{"time", Order.Descending}}){0}[target_sale], type number}
    }),
#"Expanded data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "data", {"time", "sale"}, {"time", "sale"}),
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded data",{{"index", type number}}),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Changed Type", List.Distinct(#"Changed Type"[time]), "time", "sale", List.Sum)
in  #"Pivoted Column"
```

[image]